# Is there a qualifier exclusively for Android TV

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-tv

One can use qualifiers such as mdpi, hdpi, xhdp for drawables (drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi,...).  Is there a way to have drawables exclusively for Android TV?  In other words, even if a tablet has an Android TV like resolution (e.g. 1080p), it will not pick up those drawables.

Comment: You can use `-television`. This may or may not work for any given Android set-top box, though I would expect official Android TV to use it.

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  I was reading the qualifier page, could not find this.  Out of curiosity, is this documented anywhere? https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources -- see Table 2, "UI mode" row.

Comment: Thank you.  I think this should be the answer.  Could you turn your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `-television` as a resource set qualifier. While I would expect official Android TV environments to support this, as well as "major brand" Android TV environments (e.g., Amazon Fire TV), not every Android-powered TV-centric device will. Simply put, there is no requirement for a device manufacturer to tell you that your app is running on a television-ish screen.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This clarifies quite a few things.

Answer (score 1):

Not strictly an answer to you question, but a clarification.

The way the SDK was designed is that you have a special Activity for TV (using the LEANBACK intent filter) and on that Activity you use whatever you need that is special for TV.

It's made this way to enforce the creation of special Activities for TV and not reusing the layouts for phones and tablets. Also navigation may be quite different, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I know we are not following the guideline for TV app, but our app is not a typical TV app.  It is a tool that many users want very much to run on their Android TV.

Comment: You may still want to create a special layout / UI for the TV, the usability paradigm is quite different.